# LDAP authentification and sub-directories

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap

My apache server is using the LDAP to authenticate users when they want to access the root of the server.

I'd like to add another authentification (without prompt) to allow/forbid groups of users (defined in a file on the server), which are already authenticated on the website, to access pages in specific directories.

How could I do this in my apache configuration file ?

Currently it looks like that:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName some.ip.address

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert.key

    <Directory /var/www/mywebsite>
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from All

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "LDAP Access - Mywebsite"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://myldapserver:389/ou=mygroup,dc=mydc,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)"

        AuthLDAPBindDN "uid=someuser,ou=apache,dc=mydc,dc=com"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "mysuperpassword"
        Require valid-user
        Satisfy all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mywebsite/directory>
        #What do I put in here ?
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming what you want is to allow all valid users (but no un-authenticated users) to access most of your website, but only allow a handful of users or groups to access some areas, what you'll need to do is something like:

```
<Directory /var/www/mywebsite>
   # Ldap authentication bits here as now
</Directory>
<Location /secure/>
   <RequireAll>
      Require group secure
      Require not group sales
   </RequireAll>
</Location>
<Location /secure/jim/>
   <RequireAll>
      Require user jim
   </RequireAll>
</Location>
```

Alternately, if you're still stuck on Apache 2.2, you'd instead go for something like:

```
<Directory /var/www/mywebsite>
   # Ldap authentication bits here as now
</Directory>
<Location /secure/>
   Require ldap-group cn=secure
   # Negative matching not possible with 2.2
</Location>
<Location /secure/jim/>
   Require ldap-user jim
</Location>
```

With that setup, all valid users could access `/` as now, along with most of the site. Then, on 2.4, only people who were in the LDAP group `secure` but *not* in LDAP group `sales` would be able to access things under `/secure/` (with 2.2 it's just those in the `secure` group who could). Users wouldn't be prompted to re-authenticate, their existing authentication would be re-used, with usernames/groups checked. Finally, things under `/secure/jim/` would only be visible to jim.

You can find the documentation on the different require options [in the Apache HTTPD 2.4 docs under mod_authz_core / Require](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require). For Apache 2.2, you'd need the [Apache HTTPD 2.2 docs for mod_authnz_ldap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html)

Comment: Thank you I'm going to try this asap. And where should I define the group file attribute ?

Comment: The <RequireAll> instruction isn't working... "Invalid command '<RequireAll', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

Comment: What version of Apache are you running? 2.4 as the tag on your question says, or something older?

Comment: Your groups should be defined in ldap, Apache will pull the group membership information through from the ldap server

Comment: It is running Apache v2.2.22 (Ubuntu).

Comment: Okay for the groups but what about the RequireAll instruction which isn't workin ?

Comment: RequireAll is a 2.4+ feature, which is what you tagged your question with... Version numbers matter!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24915/discussion-between-gotgot1995-and-gagravarr).